# JavascriptCore not exporting methods from clases

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, javascriptcore

I'm trying to call a method from a singleton instance of a swift class.

Here is my protocol:

```
@objc public protocol MyProtocol: JSExport {

    var name: String { get set }

    func sum(a:Int, b: Int) -> Int
}
```

And here is my class:

```
private let sharedInstance = MySingleton()

@objc public class MySingleton: NSObject, MyProtocol {

    // Singleton
    public class var sharedApp : MySingleton {

        return sharedInstance
    }    

    public var username: String

    override private init() {

        self.username = "Oscar"

        super.init()
    }

    public func sum(a: Int, b: Int) -> Int {

        return a + b
    }
}
```

I ran some tests. When I'm accessing a property it passes:

```
func testName() {

    var virtualMachine = JSVirtualMachine()
    js = JSContext(virtualMachine: virtualMachine)

    var singleton: MySingleton = MySingleton.sharedApp

    self.context.setObject(
        singleton.self,
        forKeyedSubscript: "Singleton")

    let name = js.evaluateScript("Singleton.username").toString()

    XCTAssertTrue(name == "Oscar", "Name is not Colossal, was " + name); // PASS!!!!!
}
```

However, when I call a method it fails:

```
func testSum() {

    var virtualMachine = JSVirtualMachine()
    js = JSContext(virtualMachine: virtualMachine)

    var singleton: MySingleton = MySingleton.sharedApp

    self.context.setObject(
        singleton.self,
        forKeyedSubscript: "Singleton")

    let name = js.evaluateScript("Singleton.sum(3, 2);").toInt32()

    XCTAssertTrue(sum == 5, "Sum was " + String(sum)); // Fails. Says sum was 0
}
```

It only works when reading/writing properties from/to the Javascript object, not when calling a method....

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just found a solution. Try this.

```
func sum(a:Int, _ /* <-- make this argument unnamed */ b: Int) -> Int
```

It seems `JSExport` doesn't support named parameters yet.

Comment: Wow, it was such a little detail

Comment: You are a lifesaver!

Answer (score 1):

JSExport do support named parameters, you just have to add them to the function name, e.g. :

swift function :

```
func myFunction(param1 : String, param2 : String, param3 : String)
```

will have to be called from javascript :

```
myFunctionParam2Param3( "a", "b", "c")
```

In your case, just call sumB() instead of sum():

```
let name = js.evaluateScript("Singleton.sumB(3, 2);").toInt32()
```